# Is there a way to set an option that will cause a PostgreSQL script to continue even if there are errors?

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, continue

Is there a command to set an option that will cause a PostgreSQL script to continue even if there are errors?

eg sometimes when I have a lot of data from a spreadsheet to insert into a table, I use a formula to create INSERT statements, and I copy the statements into a file and execute them, or copy them into a PgAdmin to run them. The accuracy is not always important and I don't want the whole process to fail because of a few records.

Syntax errors are not the issue here, just commands which fail due to some errors, like trying to create an index that already exists, or inserting a duplicate record.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Does that apply to any commands at all, not just insert commands?

Comment: Yes, that applies to all command (because nearly every statement in Postgres is transactional)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using `psql`, you want:

```
\set ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK on
```

From the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES):

> ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK
>
> When on, if a statement in a transaction block generates an error, the
>   error is ignored and the transaction continues. When interactive, such
>   errors are only ignored in interactive sessions, and not when reading
>   script files. When off (the default), a statement in a transaction
>   block that generates an error aborts the entire transaction

Comment: It works via implicit `SAVEPOINT`s, so in case there're many statements per transaction, `ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK` might decrease performance.

Comment: Yes, the implementation of ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK is not smart. We need the Oracle-like statement-level rollback.

Comment: Is there anything similar when you are querying database from a program?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but I was doing some research on the subject and found an excellent writeup here:  [Postgres ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK explained](https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2015/02/postgres-onerrorrollback-explained/)