# Migrate data with INSERT INTO for POSTGRESQL with constraints violated

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, insert-into

Assume I have two tables, oldstatistics and statistics, the newer table has a different constraint on the time column.

For example the newer table has the following contraint and the old table has data which violates:

> CONSTRAINT check_ts_2013_03 CHECK (statistictime >= '2013-03-01
>   01:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone AND statistictime < '2013-04-01
>   02:00:00+02'::timestamp with time zone)

and data that violates let's say they have statistictime '2013-04-01 00:15:00+01'

I found some solution for SQLite with [INSERT OR IGNORE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) (if a constraint violation occurs the rows will be skipped, and it will continue) , but not for POSTGRESQL.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: and possible duplicate of [Is there a way to set an option that will cause a PostgreSQL script to continue even if there are errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14908451/1288184) :)

Comment: @SimoKivistö The answer specified in your linked question is using psql, but this is not my case, as I'm using psycopg2 module with python.

Comment: @valentin_nasta You can use `DO` to run PL/pgSQL in ordinary SQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-do.html or create a stored function.

Comment: Sorry I confused `psql` with `pgsql` ..., but still you can solve your problem with pgSQL as it supports row by row processing (procedural statements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a plpgsql function and a EXCEPTION block (see [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html)):

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION insert_or_ignore() RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE _value timestamp;

BEGIN
  FOR _value IN SELECT statistictime FROM oldstatistics LOOP   
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO statistics(statistictime) VALUES (_value);
    EXCEPTION when check_violation THEN
       -- DO NOTHING
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- run the function
SELECT insert_or_ignore();
```

You probably need to insert also other columns, not only `statistictime`. In this case you must declare them in the DECLARE block.
You can also use the DO statement to do the same thing without create a function first (see [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-do.html):

```
DO $$
DECLARE _value timestamp;    
BEGIN
      FOR _value IN SELECT statistictime FROM oldstatistics LOOP   
        BEGIN
          INSERT INTO statistics(statistictime) VALUES (_value);
        EXCEPTION when check_violation THEN
           -- DO NOTHING
        END;
      END LOOP;
END$$;
```

I'm catching here the "check_violation" exception, but check out also all  PostgreSQL error codes, for the case you want to catch other kind of errors: [error codes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/errcodes-appendix.html)

Comment: ERROR: new row for relation "statistics_2013_03" violates check constraint "check_ts_2013_03"
SQL state: 23514

Indeed is check_violation. The problem is that it goes on EXCEPTION branch at the first fail.
But I want to continue the inserting and ignore, those ones that don't fit.

Comment: Ops, sorry. I changed my answer, check again.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with those datas, wanna merge them ?

- For using both tables I recommend to use a view.
- If you want to insert oldStatisticTime into statisticTime without modifying the data, you can remove the constraint to a trigger, unable the trigger, insert the data and then enable the trigger.

Comment: I want to migrate data, from the old table to the newer one with select into, but I can't because of the constraint.
I don't have any trigger in place.
Should I add one?

Comment: A constraint on a table consist of a table saying 'those data are is this shape'; while a trigger (on insert ei) says 'all new data will fit these condition(s)'

That's why I'd recommend to add a trigger instead of a constraint if you keep the data the same way. Especially if your other option is to bypass your own constraint

Comment: I understand, but unfortunately I'm not allowed to remove the constraint. Will look more for some solution. I might iterate on the rows and figure it out on which partition should the data fit.